# GA4 show real time urls

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

on the previous Google analytics, under `realtime` -> `overview` under `Top Active Pages:` i was able to see the realtime urls vistors are viewing. How do i view this on GA4?

Thank you.

Comment: did you manage to find any solution for this one?

Comment: @ArshArora nope :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible for real-time reports.
Goog guys sucks in that they released a half baked product. Hopefully the features from ua will gradually return

Comment: i totally agree